# How to find only specific key word in this zcat loop?

Tags: command-line, grep

This is what i typed and I was expected to get only the log of the user in the `""`. But I've got the whole logs in the server:

```
for i in `ls *.log.gz`; do zcat $i |  grep "U2779897722719715411" >> sara.log;  done ; *
```

What should I change in this loop to find only log with this key word?

Thank you.

Comment: What if you do `zgrep U2779897722719715411 *.log.gz > sara.log`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `zgrep` command is very useful for grepping in compressed files, and avoids your need to pipe `zcat` to `grep`. You also don't need to use the for loop to create a list of files by [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) (shell pattern matching).

```
zgrep U2779897722719715411 *.log.gz >> sara.log
```

That command will output the filename and the line containing U2779897722719715411 separated by a `:` character.

If you don't want the filename prefix, you can use the `-h` option to `zgrep`:

```
zgrep -h U2779897722719715411 *.log.gz >> sara.log
```

This can also be achieved with a loop, but avoid using `ls`, and carry out the redirection to the file after the loop completes:

```
for i in *.log.gz ; do zgrep U2779897722719715411 "$i" ; done >> sara.log
```

Alternatively if you only want the filename of files that contain that user string U2779897722719715411, you can use the `-l` option to `zgrep` in either of the above commands:

```
zgrep -l U2779897722719715411 *.log.gz >> sara.log
```

or

```
for i in *.log.gz ; do zgrep -l U2779897722719715411 "$i" ; done >> sara.log
```